# Meu acesso está sendo negado ao executar o seguinte codigo

Tags: c#

```
private void GerarPDF(string pCaminhoArquivoPDF)
{
    Document doc = new Document();

    // Aqui acontece o erro
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pCaminhoArquivoPDF,FileMode.Create));

    try
    {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(textBox1.Text);
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(p);
        doc.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        //throw;
    }
}

private void OndeGerar(Object o,EventArgs e)
{
    GerarPDF( @"C:\Users\CAIO\Desktop\PDF's");
}
```

Comment: Tente executar o Visual Studio no modo administrador.

Comment: Normalmente erro de acesso negado pode ser que o caminho que você está tentando acessar nem exista. Já aconteceu isso comigo e fiquei pensando que poderia ser algo de acesso, mas no fim, era eu quem estava passando o caminho errado!

Comment: Pode esse apóstrofo aí, do `PDF's`?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Pode sim "Arnaldo" :)

Answer (score 0):

O problema poderá ter origem em dois pontos:

- Permissões de escrita na pasta `C:\Users\CAIO\Desktop\PDF's`

  - Neste caso atribuir permissões de escrita ao utilizador
- Falta de previlégios de escrita a partir do próprio **Visual Studio** (ou do IDE que está a utilizar para executar o código)

  - Neste caso executar o IDE em modo de **Administrador**

O facto da pasta "*PDF's*" ter uma plica ou apóstrofe também não ajuda muito, pode estar a provocar algum problema na criação do ficheiro. Pode até nem representar um problema, mas de qualquer forma deveria rever o nome.